# asyncore callbacks launching threads... ok to do?

Tags: python, multithreading, couchdb, asyncore

I'm unfamiliar with [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html), and have very limited knowledge of asynchronous programming except for a few intro to twisted tutorials.

I am most familiar with threads and use them in all my apps. One particular app uses a [couchdb](http://www.couchone.com/) database as its interface. This involves longpolling the db looking for changes and updates. The module I use for couchdb is [couchdbkit](http://couchdbkit.org/). It uses an asyncore loop to watch for these changes and send them to a callback.

So, I figure from this callback is where I launch my worker threads. It seems a bit crude to mix asynchronous and threaded programming. I really like couchdbkit, but would rather not introduce issues into my program.

So, my question is, is it safe to fire threads from an async callback?

Here's some code...

```
def dispatch(change):
    global jobs, db_url # jobs is my queue
    db = Database(db_url)
    work_order = db.get(change['id']) # change is an id to the document that changed. 
                                  # i need to get the actual document (workorder)

    worker = Worker(work_order, db) # fire the thread
    jobs.append(worker)
    worker.start()
    return


main()
.
.
.

consumer.wait(cb=dispatch, since=update_seq, timeout=10000) #wait constains the asyncloop.
```

Update:

After looking over this more, I have an additional question for the couchdbkit gurus. There will potentially be hundreds of threads using the database. As you can see in my code sample, I am instantiating a couchdbkit.Database object per thread. I think this may be wasteful. So, is it ok for a single database object to be used globally among the threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this create a new thread every time the server returns a new document? I would guess that you are best creating a pool of worker threads *before* you call anything on the server, and just add a job to the queue that these threads are reading their work from in the `dispatch` method.

But there is no reason why mixing threading and asynchronous programming should be considered dangerous.

Comment: Yea creating a new thread per work order is the idea. Each worker will open a tunnel and perform various maintenance tasks on a remote device. I haven't considered a thread pool, but maybe given how callbacks are used this may e a good idea. Thanks for for the input.